# App not coming up: SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Tags: openshift, jboss-eap-6

I am using Tomcat 7 JBOSS EWS2.0 for my web application. My build and deployments are fine but app is giving 404 error. Upon checking the jbossews logs, I see S

> EVERE: Error listenerStart

. App is running fine on my local. I have gone through threads on stackoverflow but didn't find much help. Any thoughts are really appreciated.

Logs:

```
    ==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.229.129-8080"]
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.229.129-8080"]
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2393 ms
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2393 ms
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/539c7d5ce0b8cddb51000076/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/539c7d5ce0b8cddb51000076/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.229.129-8080"]
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.8.229.129-8080"]
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 23458 ms
Jul 26, 2014 8:53:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 23458 ms
```

Comment: It seems like there's some information missing in that log. You may need to configure log4j or something. Is there another log file around? Can you attach a debugger?

Comment: I am unable to find tomcat logs on openshift via ssh, any idea? I have added logging.properties to WEB-INF/classes but no impact on jbossews logs

Comment: @nickgroenke: restarted app with -t option and changing pom.xml to have war as ROOT.war. Replaced logs with this output. Not sure if that can be of any help. Please advise.

Comment: What's in your logging.properties? Something like this? org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Comment: @nickgroenke: I had changed INFO to ERROR. Here is my snippet. `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ERROR
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`